# Quadrants of points located in the x and y axes

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Which quadrant are the points that lie on the axis in? (e.g. the points $(0, 2)$ or $(4, 0)$)

Comment: The axes are typically defined such that they are not contained in any quadrant.

Answer (score 5):

Your question itself has the answer.

> points that **lie on the axis**

The points that lie on an axis do not lie in any quadrant. If a point lies on the $x$-axis then its $y$-coordinate is $0$. Similarly, for the $y$-axis.

Answer (score 2):

The equation of the $X$-axis is $y=0$ and that of $Y$-axis is $x=0$.

Your given two points $(0,2)$ lies on the positive $Y$-axis, which is the boundary between the first and second quadrant and $(4,0)$ lies on the positive $X$-axis, which is the boundary between the first and fourth quadrant.

The following picture make your concept more clear about that fact

[image]